# syntax of apply-template in xml stylesheet

Tags: xml, stylesheet

there is  a variable named "this-article" in the  following code.

Generally, We use "xsl:apply-templates" in this way

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="somenode"/>
```

"somenode" means a child node.

---

but in this variable , apply-template was written in this way. it is strange.

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="id"/>
```

I would appreciate if you explain the meaning of it.

```
<!-- ============================================================= -->
<!--  "make-article" for the document architecture                 -->
<!-- ============================================================= -->

  <xsl:template name="make-article">
    <!-- Generates a series of (flattened) divs for contents of any
           article, sub-article or response -->

    <!-- variable to be used in div id's to keep them unique -->
    <xsl:variable name="this-article">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="id"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <div id="{$this-article}-front" class="front">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="front | front-stub"/>
    </div>

    <!-- body -->
    <xsl:for-each select="body">
      <div id="{$this-article}-body" class="body">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:if test="back | $loose-footnotes">
      <!-- $loose-footnotes is defined below as any footnotes outside
           front matter or fn-group -->
      <div id="{$this-article}-back" class="back">
        <xsl:call-template name="make-back"/>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:for-each select="floats-group">
      <div id="{$this-article}-floats" class="back">
        <xsl:call-template name="main-title">
          <xsl:with-param name="contents">
            <span class="generated">Floating objects</span>
          </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <!-- more metadata goes in the footer -->
    <div id="{$this-article}-footer" class="footer">
      <xsl:call-template name="footer-metadata"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="footer-branding"/>
    </div>

    <!-- sub-article or response (recursively calls
             this template) -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sub-article | response"/>

  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what this code is doing, but it's a common enough design pattern. Let's say you want to decide whether to display elements (or omit them) based on their "importance". Then you might have a set of rules for calculating the importance of an element:

```
<xsl:template match="p" mode="importance">high</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[@class='x']" mode="importance">medium</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="emph[@class='x']" mode="importance">low</xsl:template>
```

To compute the importance of the current element you can then do

```
<xsl:variable name="importance">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="importance"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

This kind of code is typically written by someone who has thoroughly mastered the value of template rules in enabling extensible, rule-based, reusable and polymorphic code to be developed. It's well worth reading such code and learning from it.